# Assigning a string (from a list of string) to a dataframe name pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of names, `['name1', 'name2',... 'nameN']`, that I would like to use as names for the resulting dataframes after filtering the original dataframe by each name in a for loop

```
name1 = originaldf[originaldf.names = 'name1']
```

Is there a function in python, similar to assign in R, that I can use to accomplish this. Any other solutions are welcome.

As requested. Here is an example:

```
names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']

f = pd.DataFrame({'names' : np.random.choice(names, size=15)})
name1 = df[df.names=='name1']
name2 = df[df.names=='name2']
name3 = df[df.names=='name3']

# Then: 
display(name1, name2, name3)

names
1   name1
2   name1
3   name1
4   name1
5   name1
names
0   name2
7   name2
names
6   name3
8   name3
9   name3
10  name3
11  name3
12  name3
13  name3
14  name3
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with your desired output.

Comment: Perhaps consider storing them in a dictionary, with the keys as the names and values the DataFrames

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you dynamically create variables via a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setattr for this, but i (as others) strongly recommend using a dictionary .

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

thismodule = sys.modules[__name__]
names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']

for i in names:
    setattr(thismodule, i,df[df.names==i])

display(name1,name2,name3)
```

This sets a dataframe to each value in names

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you share the reasoning for using the dictionary method over the setattr method?

Comment: The main practical reason to have a dictionary is that it simplify questions that use many dataframes. like "What is the max value in each frame?".

referencing the frames would be d["name1"] with dictionary vs name1 with setattr.  Which is not much more difficult.

Comment: Thanks. I think setattr is perfect for what I am doing.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. In Python to create a dataframe based on a name stored as a string you can use globals() like this:

```
name = 'name1'
globals()[name] = df
```

In this example, df is the copy of the dataframe you're trying to rename, so in your example that should be:

```
names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
for n in names:
    globals()[n] = df[df.names==n]
```